# Keeping a copy of each generated ad

Tags: javascript, ads, adsense

Since most AdNetworks generate ads via their scripts dynamically, are there ways to save the generated ad? So if AdSense generated ads for my 10000 visitors, I hope to have a copy of each ad generated. Would I need to find a way to scrape my page on each visit? I hope to find a solution for both flash and non-flash ads.

Comment: My guess is that storing the content provided by these add services violates their TOS and could put you in some _hot_ water. It might help to know _why_ you want to do this.

Comment: I guess its not allowed by their agreements.

Comment: @cdeszaq I'm trying to see what ads my visitors actually have seen.

Comment: The ads are served from 3rd party servers. Your server would not have access to them at all, since they're retrieved purely by the client browsers. And the ads served depend a lot on the IP/previous tracking history for each user, so if your server tried to fetch the ads itself, it would get something different than what the clients did.

Comment: If you only want to see what your visitors see, then just fire up a browser and take a look!

Comment: Scraping an ad from server side after it has been displayed would constitute a *second* request, causing the ad's view counter to be  incremented. This would almost certainly be viewed as fraud by the ad provider. Also, since you're accessing the ad from a different IP, you would probably see something different anyway. If it's possible at all, then only in JavaScript - but it would have to involve uploading the ad's image data to your server so you can store it. And even if that isn't blocked by the Same Origin Policy anyway - do you want to do that to your visitors?

Comment: @cdeszaq but that's what I see, not exactly what my visitors have seen.

Comment: but you still haven't really told us _why_ you want to see the ads your users see...

Comment: I feel it is a reasonable request to see what ads are being displayed on one's own web site, but this is the ad provider's job to implement, not the site owner's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. it's against the TOS. If you're that worried about it, filter the ads in your admin panel or find another ad solution.